# Document base /usr/share/tomcat7/webapps/ROOT does not exist or is not a readable directory

Tags: tomcat, amazon-ec2

I have a Tomcat application at `/var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/ROOT` on an Amazon EC2 instance.  It has worked fine until today, when I began to receive an error in the catalina.out logs while starting the server.

When accessing pages in a web browser, every page is blank (even pages which do not exist), the favicon displays and there are no errors.

I believe this started happening after performing an `rsync --delete -zav` from my local machine to `/var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/ROOT`, although I am sure no important files were deleted.

```
SEVERE: Error starting static Resources
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Document base /usr/share/tomcat7/webapps/ROOT does not exist or is not a readable directory
    at org.apache.naming.resources.FileDirContext.setDocBase(FileDirContext.java:138)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.resourcesStart(StandardContext.java:5055)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5235)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:633)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:1120)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDirectory.run(HostConfig.java:1678)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

The strange part is that `/usr/share/tomcat7/webapps/` is a symbolic link to `/var/lib/tomcat7/webapps`, so the app definitely exists at that location.  Why does this error occur, and how can it be fixed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible that `rsync` has changed the ownership or permissions of your webapp files (because of the `a` switch). Make sure that the directories and files are readable by the user running the Tomcat process.